# Zoom after search using autocomplete

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, jquery

How to do after a search, zoom in on the value found on the map? My code is:

```
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
    source: setoresComerciais.features.map(function(d){
        return d.properties.sco_num_sc + " - " + d.properties.sco_dsc_loc
    }),
    select: function(event, ui){
        map.fitBounds(stComerciaisLayer.getBounds(ui.item.value));
    } 
});
```

First, I get `return d.properties.sco_num_sc + " - " + d.properties.sco_dsc_loc`, this return, for example: `1 - FORTALEZA`
After, I use select, where have the param `ui`, when do `ui.item.value` return `1 - FORTALEZA`, so this:

```
map.fitBounds(stComerciaisLayer.getBounds(ui.item.value));
```

Where:

```
stComerciaisLayer = L.geoJSON(setoresComerciais, {
                style: function (feature) {
                    return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
                },
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
(...)
```

It was to return exactly what I wanted, the result of the search and the zoom in it, but don't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Seriously, no clear GIS component? This was an issue with Leaflet JS, search and zoom. How many other software packages that are not GIS,  zoom to a GeoJSON feature. The other sites would throw it back to GIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see enough code above to troubleshoot, but I may be able to help.

Here is a write up and example I created for a class. My clue was tagging the  layer._leaflet_id with the a feature attribute, then using this as my search results value, which happens in your onEachFeature function.

Hope this helps explain it: http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Search/index.html

Working example: http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Search/SearchState.html

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's exactly what I needed. I searched a lot and did not find an example like I wanted, but this will work!